# Unable to synchronize Magento site products with MRPEasy app

Tags: magento2

I'm running **Magento 2.1.8.** I've installed `MRPEasy integration extension` and configured the API key, access key on my Magento application.

I'm not able to synchronize my site products, orders, customers and other details with **MRPEasy cloud-based app.**

When I try to Synchronize, it shows the last synchronization time. but it doesn't show the **synchronized products, orders, customers and other details in the MRPEasy app**.

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated.